# ¿Por qué detecta error de Sintaxis en la línea 3? AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Alguien que sepa el porque indica el Error: Function calls require a space or "(".  Use comma only between parameters.

Me indica que mi error se encuentra en la linea 3 que es: Run, C:\Windows\System32\fsquirt.exe

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
!j::
Run, C:\Windows\System32\fsquirt.exe
Sleep 500
SendInput, {Down}
SendInput, {Enter}
return
```

Comment: [La documentación](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Run.htm) dice que es `Run Target`; es decir, **sin** esa coma.

Comment: @Trauma Al eliminar la coma me aparece el Error: Hotkey or hotstring is missing its opening brace.
Y si coloco { } rodeando la dirección de mi .exe me indica el mismo error, estoy un poco bloqueado sobre como poder resolverlo.